# Django file upload:Integrity Error

Tags: django

This is what I got

```
IntegrityError at /malex/upload/
NOT NULL constraint failed: malex_document.uploaded_by_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/malex/upload/
Django Version: 2.0.5
Exception Type: IntegrityError
```

Models

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    password = models.TextField(max_length=80,blank=True)

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Forms

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a file')
```

views

```
def upload(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
            **newdoc.uploaded_by = request.user.profile**
            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render(request,'upload.html',{'documents': documents, 'form': form})
```

If I add the line as neverwalker alone has suggested

```
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'profile'
```

What even makes things more strange with this integrity error is that the file is uploaded

```
~/nup/malex/media/documents/2018/06/22$ ls -lh 262_V01_C06_R000_TEy_BH_131072H.ats
-rw------- 1 milenko milenko 46M јун 22 07:22 262_V01_C06_R000_TEy_BH_131072H.ats
```

Why do I got this error and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set `uploaded_by` attribute. Since it's not nullable this is raise error. To fix this, you need to provide `uploaded_by` to new Document instance before saving like this:

```
@login_required
def upload(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.uploaded_by = request.user.profile # if Profile has onetofield with User model
            # newdoc.uploaded_by = request.user if Profile is your user_model 
            newdoc.save()
```

Note uose login_required decorator to ensure current user is authenticated.

Also you can set `uploaded_by` as nullable field:

```
uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

In this case `uploaded_by` will not required, and will be set as ULL for new records.

Comment: Well,now I have issue that user is Anonimous.Take a look at my edit please!

Comment: @RichardRublev you need to log in first. You can use login_required decorator for this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator